# $7$ points and $10$ sides $\overset{?}{\Longrightarrow}$ a quadrilateral

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> Show that there exists a quadrilateral in graph $G$ with $7$ vertices and $10$ sides.
>
> More generally, show that there exists a quadrilateral in a graph with $n$ vertices and $l$ sides where $$q\ge2,n=q^2+q+1,l\ge\frac12q(q+1)^2+1.$$

The simplest way of tracking quadrilaterals is to count angles. If $$A,B,C\in V;AB,BC\in E$$ then call this structure an angle. Two angles with the same pair of vertices sticking out form a quadrilateral. So we want to show that the number of angles exceeds the number of vertex pairs.

Let the degree of vertices of $G$ be $d_i(i\in[1,7])$. Then the number of angles is $S=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^7\mbox C_{d_i}^2$.

If there $\exists i,j$ for which $d_i-d_j\ge2$, let $$d_i’=d_i-1,d_j’=d_j+1$$ and we have $$\mbox C_{d_i}^2+C_{d_j}^2>C_{d_i’}^2+C_{d_j’}^2\Longrightarrow S>S’.$$ This points out that the minimum of $S$ is reached when $d_1=2,d_2=\cdots=d_7=3$ or any other order. It is $$S_\min=6\times\mbox C_3^2+\mbox C_2^2=19<\mbox C_7^2=21.$$ Very unfortunately we didn’t reach our goal.

In conclusion we need **a more accurate way of counting quadrilaterals**.

Comment: This is Furedi's theorem, 1983: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895683900187/pdf?md5=45f916efb775174a01057ce13275bc7e&pid=1-s2.0-0095895683900187-main.pdf

Comment: It is convenient to take a more asymmetrical approach and consider one of the vertices with maximum degree as a "root" and count angles in the complement.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio The paper you linked only deals with $q=2^k$. Is the case for general $q$ an open problem, do you know?

Comment: It has been completely settled: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82188991.pdf

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio It says 403 forbidden :(

Comment: The second link from @JackD'Aurizio is Furedi "On the number of edges of quadrilateral-free graphs" JCTB 68 (1996) 1-6.

Comment: Is this an assignment from university?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel No, I’m in middle school and this is a math Olympiad problem.

Comment: They've underestimated the difficulty of the problem then. (If $q$ is restricted to be a prime power though it would be somewhat easier.)